# boost::asio::windows::stream_handle.async_read_some can't work with null_buffers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I know that boost asio can be integrated with third-party libraries in a reactor-style. [Here](http://think-async.com/asio/boost_asio_1_4_7/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) is the example I have found. It is demostrated with a socket and it works perfectly fine. But when I use boost::windows::stream_handle in stead of socket to deal with file descriptors, it doesn't compile. Here's the example code:

```
void Func(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes)
{

}
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    TCP::socket sock(io_service);
    sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(), Func); //1

    HANDLE h;
    char buf[20];
    boost::asio::windows::stream_handle Handle(io_service, h);
    Handle.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 20), Func);  //2
    //Handle.async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(), Func); //3
    return 0;
}
```

line 1 and line 2 can compile, but if I uncomment line 3, I would get a whole bunch of errors. Here's  part of the errors:

> F:\Lib\boost\include\boost-1_54/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_handle_service.hpp:265:8: error: 'void boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_handle_service::async_read_some(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_handle_service::implementation_type&, const boost::asio::null_buffers&, Handler&) [with Handler = void (*)(boost::system::error_code, unsigned int)]' is private

It seems the function has been declared with **private**. Does anyone knows why? Is there a workaround here?

Comment: Comments in `win_iocp_handle_service.hpp` state it's intentional: *"// Prevent the use of the null_buffers type with this service."* I guess it's because using `null_buffers` with `stream_handle` doesn't make sense, as `stream_handle` is always ready to perform i/o.

Comment: Since null_buffers cannot be used here, is there a way to deal with raw socket/file descriptor of windows in a reactor style boost asio?

Comment: Regarding raw sockets, consider using [basic_raw_socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket.html) , if it meets your specific needs. As for file, you could perform direct `read_some` in your reactor loop, because file i/o never blocks on Windows AFAIK, couldn't you?